# How get and set custom code and message from exception in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here is an example of an endpoint that I have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Portfolio")]
    [ActionName("LoadNew")]
    public async Task<List<RF_PORTFOLIO>> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        List<RF_PORTFOLIO> ProfileList = new List<RF_PORTFOLIO>();
                try
                {
                    using (var context = new AMLPContext())
                    {
                        using (var manager = new PortfolioManager(context))
                        {
                            ProfileList = await manager.ProfileLoad(cancellationToken);
                        }
                        if (ProfileList.Count() == 0)
                        //Throw an exception with custom status code and message
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Catch the exception and return a response with the status code and message from the exception
                }
        return ProfileList;
    }
```

Inside my `try-catch` block, I want to be able to throw an exception with the custom status code and message to indicate whether it was a bad request, or internal server error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the answer is already within stackoverflow!
Nethertheless some thoughts following

It depends on which framework you're using

if you're using  ASP.Net 4.x you can use an ExceptionAttribute

```
public class ExceptionAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // handle the error
    }
 }
 //// configuration.Filters.Add(new ExceptionAttribute()); this is how it's registered within HttpConfiguration
```

if you're using ASP.Net 4.x with Owin you could use an ExceptionMiddleware

```
public class GlobalExceptionMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    //// middleware registered app.Use<GlobalExceptionMiddleware>(); => IAppBuilder
    try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //// bug in webapi, response should be delivered but the client is already disconnected
            if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
}
```

if you're using .NetCore I'd also propose to use an middleware component which ist registered also in first place

```
public class RequestMiddleware 
{
    public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger log)
    {
        _next = next;
        _Log = log;
    }
    
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
       try {
           await _next(context);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           //// do your error handling
       }
    }
}
```